# using 'how many' with a number and a noun

Tags: grammatical-number

We can say:

How many hundreds are there in a thousand?

We can also say:

How many years will it take?

Do we say?

```
How many thousands of years will it take?
```

How many+  number + of+ Plural noun

Answer (score 1):

> How many thousands of years will it take?

Yes, that is correct.

**Other examples**

*How many days will it take?*

*How many millions of years will it take?*

*How many centuries will it take?*

and

*How many pints of beer will it take for me to get drunk?*

---

**You may also be interested in the words of this famous song**

> “Blowin' in the Wind” by Bob Dylan
>
> How many roads must a man walk down
>  Before you call him a man?
> How many seas must a white dove sail
>  Before she sleeps in the
> sand?
>  Yes, and how many times must the cannonballs fly
>  Before
> they're forever banned?
>
> [Refrain]
>  The answer, my friend, is blowin' in the wind
>  The
> answer is blowin' in the wind
>
> [Verse 2]
>  Yes, and how many years can a mountain exist
>  Before it
> is washed to the sea?
>  Yes, and how many years can some people
> exist
>  Before they're allowed to be free?
>  Yes, and how many
> times can a man turn his head
>
> https://genius.com/Bob-dylan-blowin-in-the-wind-lyrics